# Check if display is broken or gpio problem

Tags: gpio, python, display

I bought `ST7735` 128x160 display and I run it with [this](https://jakew.me/2018/01/19/st7735-pi/) code

The first time I ran it, it worked, but cables were connected through a breadboard. So I decided to connect it straight to GPIO - I took a photo, shut down the Pi and remade the connection.
After the system restart I tried to run the same code, but the display remains white, without output there. I checked the connection about 5 times and it's the same as before.
Could the system restart have some effect on it? Or maybe GPIO failure? I also tried to change the cables, but nothing changed.

Is there a way to check if the display is connected to GPIO? Some `GPIO bit output`, or something like that?

Connection I made are same as the link above

Comment: go back to setup that worked, i.e. through breadboard ... if it works, good ... if it doesn't work now, you may have damaged the display or pi or both

Comment: @JaromandaX hey I just realized I used 3V instead of 5V pin for VCC, could this be the problem? I read that the display supports 3.3V or 5V and display was white, so there was an electricity I think... Anyway I'm not able to check it till weekend

Comment: I wouldn't know - I'd be careful with 5V devices on a Pi - its GPIO don't like 5V - though, I guess that device doesn't have any output, only input